# AS3 webcam shape recognition

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, webcam, motion

I'm making a dissertation on webcam motion tracking in actionscript. I am looking at different possibilities on how to do this and have found a few already.

There is, however, one method I would like to try out, but i'm kind of stuck. I'm trying to achieve body shape recognition (preferably a hand). Does anyone have any ideas on how I could achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem in another way: i am not using shape recognition, which was actually to difficult to achieve (and computationally very challenging for flash), but i am now using colored objects for tracking :)

Answer (score 0):

Not an easy problem. OpenCV has motion tracking but you would have to adapt it's code to as3. This is a fairly computationally difficult task for as3 too.

http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into it ;) and I know this will push the system to its limits, but that is what I want to test.